# Subscription type variable declaration issue in ionic 4

Tags: rxjs, ionic4, subscription

I have this error for `subscription` type variable declaration issue in ionic

> Module '"../../../../node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported
>   member 'Subscription'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the import code.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

to

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

// For ionic 4